# D3 Chord Example Hover Issue in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, internet-explorer-11

I'm working through some examples of how to construct chord diagrams in D3 from a tutorial I found at http://www.delimited.io/blog/2013/12/8/chord-diagrams-in-d3

I'm looking at the first example, about hair colour preference. When you hover over a group around the edge of the circle, it shows only the chords related to that group, and when you move the mouse outside the circle again, all the other chords reappear.

This seems to be achieved by dynamically appending the css class "fade" to all the chords that are supposed to be hidden, and then the following piece of CSS handles hiding them all on hover.

```
#circle:hover path.fade {
  display: none;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but when I try the same page in IE11, once you have hovered over one group, the remaining chords are never redrawn when you move the mouse outside the circle.

I fired up the debugger in IE11, and it seems that simply modifying one of the properties on the DOM whilst in the debugger resolves the issue - but I'm having trouble figuring out how I can achieve this in code.

I've created a fiddle here with all the details https://jsfiddle.net/49dym52r/

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Can you share the full version number of Internet Explorer, as well as the Windows version?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18125,
Windows 8.1 (Version 6.3 (Build 9600)) reported from winver @Sampson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the issue when viewing the [delimited.io resource](http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/chord-diagrams/debt.html) in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10. I am not, however, able to reproduce the issue in Microsoft Edge, which likely means the fix came in as part of additional web platform work done on EdgeHTML after the fork from Trident.

It's unlikely that we will be doing any feature-work on Internet Explorer, so your best option is going to be persuading Internet Explorer 11 into behaving more appropriately. This can sometimes be tricky, but after a couple of minutes in [Telerik's Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I was able to resolve the problem in Internet Explorer 11 on my build of Windows 10 with the following addition:

```
div:hover { background: auto } // Or svg:hover, per the comments below
```

I added this to the top of the aforementioned delimited.io resource, and it appears to have resolved the issue for me. It's a bit heavy-handed, so you may want to adjust its scope if you find it causes you any issues.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, if I append your CSS to either the JsFiddle or the static HTML version I have locally, the problem still persists.

Could it be that Fiddler has also "poked" the DOM somehow during insertion of that CSS into the page, which has achieved the same effects as toggling a style setting in the IE debugger? @Sampson

Comment: Fiddler doesn't touch the DOM. Can you share a .zip of your local project?

Comment: Sure, it's here http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=67450144982936170949 @Sampson

Comment: @Hoodlum Minor variation, but adding `svg:hover { background: auto }` on line 7-9 appears to resolve the issue for me for IE 11 on Windows 10.